# What is the relationship between stack names on the ROS wiki and its repository's name?

Tags: ros, stacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our lab hosts code with Google Code and was planing on releasing each stack as a separate repository.  Unfortunately, this scheme also generates very ugly repostority URLs as repository names aren't allowed to have underscores (which I've replaced with dashes) but this isn't a preferred ROS naming convention as I understand it.  Also, the repository name is also prepended with Google Code project name: https://code.google.com/p/gt-ros-pkg.my-stack-name/

My question is what happens when a repository with this name gets indexed and linked to a page on the wiki? Is there a way to turn "gt-ros-pkg.my-stack-name" to something more friendly like "my_stack_name"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32226/what-is-the-relationship-between-stack-names-on-the-ros-wiki-and-its-repository%27s-name?/) by [haidai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1020/haidai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you start moving to individual stack repositories, the best solution is to submit a web-accessible rosinstall for indexing (simply e-mail the link to ros-users).  rosinstall's "local-name" attribute will ensure that the stack has the correct name when it is indexed.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-27**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Repositories/IndexSubmission